# Attempt to prove: $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, for every $c \in [0,1]$ the limit $ \lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ exists, so $f$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ such that for every $c \in [0,1]$ the limit $ \lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ exists (and finite). Prove that $f$ is bounded.

My attempt:

For every $c \in [0,1]$ there exists $\delta_c >0$ such that for every $x\in I_c=(c-\delta_c, c+\delta_c)$, $L_c-1<f(x)<L_c+1$. Mark $K_c=\max \{|L_c+1|, |L_c-1|\}$.

The open intervals $(c-\delta_c, c+\delta_c)$ cover $[0,1]$, and by Heine—Borel, finitely many of them, $n$, are enough to cover it.

Take $M=\max \{K_1, K_2, \dots, K_n\}$, so for every $x \in [0,1]$, $|f(x)|<M.$

Is this prove is correct? Is ther something I missed, or should add?

Comment: Looks good to me. The key is compactness of $[0,1]$, which you used in what looks like the right way.

Comment: Looks good.${}{}$

Comment: All ok. Good job.

Comment: Remarkably, this implies that $f$ is piecewise continuous. If not, we could define $f$ in discontinuity points to make it unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

Just a sidenote actually, but I'd say going for contradiction is easier.

Suppose that $f$ is unbounded. There exists some sequence $x_n \in [0,1]$ such that $\forall n, f(x_n) \geq n$.

By Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, there is some subsequence of $(x_n)$ say $x_{n_k}$ that converges to $c\in [0,1]$.

Since $\forall k, f(x_{n_k})\geq n_k$, $f$ cannot have a limit at $c$. Contradiction.

Comment: thanks, I knew that classic one, but I wanted to practice Heine—Borel

Answer (score 1):

I can only nitpick:

"finitely many of them , $n$, are enough to cover them".  True, but you should define what $K_1$, $\ldots$, $K_n$ are. Are they some $K_c$ (with $c\in[0,1]$)?

So say something like, "choose $c_1,\ldots, c_n$ in $[0,1]$ so that $[0,1]\subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n (c_i-\delta_{c_i}, c_i+\delta_{c_i})$, and set $M=\max\{K_{c_1},\ldots, K_{c_n}\}$...". (Or, "let $M$ be an upper bound of the $K_c$ corresponding to a finite subcover".)

But, nice proof!